# Top bar - UIImage link

Tags: ios

I'm using this code to display the image but I would love to link that image back to the rootView. Any suggestions?

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Invest.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Make it a property and post an `NSNotification` with the property as the object back to the rootView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, you can use an `NSNotification` to post it back to your rootView controller:

YourViewController.m: (The view controller where your image resides)

Call: `[self yourMethod];` to post the image back to the rootView

```
- (void)yourMethod
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"postImage" object:self.yourImage userInfo:nil];
}
```

RootViewController.m:

Here we need to add an observer that way we can later receive the image you want to post later from other parts of your app.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(postedImage:) name:@"postImage" object:nil];
}
```

Here we grab the notification's object as the postedImage:

```
- (void)postedImage:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIImage *postedImage = notification.object;
}
```

Don't forget dealloc method to remove the observer!

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSNotification` to "move" the data to a different ViewController.

Post the notification inside your current ViewController

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:image forKey:@"image"];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"imageNotification" object:nil userInfo:dictionary];
```

Add an observer in the `viewDidLoad` method of the other ViewController

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedImage:) name:@"imageNotification" object:nil];
```

Add a method that will get called when the notification got posted (inside the other ViewController)

```
- (void)receivedImage:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UIImage *image = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"image"];
}
```